# Wordpress function.php file older version before Update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

By mistake I copied an others theme function.php code in my current function.php file of my wordpress website. And now it is not working anymore.

Do you know if there is any way to get the function.php file version, that I had before clicking the Update button ?

Comment: Not unless you have some kind of version control system in use. I’d suggest downloading the files of your original theme again, and take the file from there to replace it on your server …

Answer (score 0):

Any modifications you made to the file will have been lost unless you were using some form of version control such as git.

Do you have any form of backups in place?

If not you'll need to download a fresh copy of the theme and copy over functions.php.

Comment: :| I wanted to use a git after I finished that modification. But now it's to late I will have to start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Original website where you buy the actual Wordpress Theme, then reach the "Download" Section, Download one more time the theme, unzip it and you got a new function.php ready to use.